# Problem externalizing pgfplot figure with two parallel LaTeX distributions

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-external

I am getting errors when trying to compile this minimal example, using both externalize function in `pgfplot`s and loading `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize% activate externalization!

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot {x^2};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Our first external graphics example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It works if I delete the `\usepackage{siunitx}` - does anyone have an idea why that is? Running TeX Live 2014 and all packages are up-to-date

Comment: Can you specify what errors you see?

Comment: ! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "externatest-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalre
aljob{externatest}\input{externatest}"' did NOT result in a usable output file
'externatest-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify th
at you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape
'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the c
ommand simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'externatest-figure0.log'.
 If you continue now, I'll try to type...

Comment: Calling it with

"C:/texlive/2014/bin/win32/pdflatex.exe" -shell-escape externatest.tex

Comment: The thing is, that the example compiles fine when I remove siunitx..

Comment: Normally you don't need the path and should not need the extension for the file. For me `pdflatex --shell-escape test` is fine.

Comment: Try without externalisation and see  if there is some other error occurring.

Comment: I need the path as I installed TeXLive without admin rights- so the path is not set on Windows. The extension is optional-
Maybe the error is related to the admin thing.

Comment: The path can be set also by a user. And as the externalize function needs to find pdflatex you should also set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ulrike, your comment pointed me in the correct direction. So I will answer myself:

I have two parallel LaTeX installations, one global, admin MikTeX with outdated/missing packages which was set as standard and a private, up-to-date TexLive version.

Calling with pdflatex with  "C:/texlive/2014/bin/win32/pdflatex.exe" correctly uses the TexLive installation and packages. But when running externalization, the standard MikTeX was called for the external figures- which then crashed because of missing siunitx.

Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the help.